# My Xbox One controller's left joystick popped out. What should I do?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, hardware

I’m sharing pictures, because this seems fairly incredible to me:

[image: Me holding my xbox controller, with the left joystick completely free]

[image: Close-up and slightly different angle]

This controller fell maybe 3 feet onto a hardwood floor, and I was amazed to discover that the joystick — which doesn’t appear to physically fit through the, uh, joystick hole! — had completely detached. It definitely does not want to "pop back in" and I am a little nervous of the prospect of disassembling and re-assembling this $50 controller in order to get the joystick back in, but is that what I should do?

(Has this happened to anyone else?)

To clarify (to best comply with Stack Exchange rules): The main question here is: **What is my best option for repairing this joystick-lite xbox controller?**

Comment: Just pull it apart and put it back together with the joystick, there are many tutorials online about how to do it without breaking your controller, which is very hard stuff up, you'll be fine

Comment: Buy a torx screwdriver for like £1 on ebay and watch a tutorial on youtube. It is incredibly difficult to break the controller from taking it apart.

Comment: Would you mind confirming that no part of the joystick itself is broken?

Comment: Confirmed - nothing seems broken. The joystick is actually usable (touching the metal directly) and the plastic appears unbroken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ended up following a YouTube controller disassembly/repair video.

Note that you only have to get to the step where you remove the front plate. I needed a T8 Security Torx screwdriver bit. (Note a regular Torx head won't work, because Microsoft hates us. Also, some tutorials will say you need a T6 Security Torx bit, but that is only required for further disassembly which is not necessary here.)

Pics:

[image: Stick reattached, faceplate off]
[image: Same]
[image: faceplate off]
[image: Back together]